# Azure Function Container is disposed and should not be used: Container is disposed

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have set up and configured Azure Function v3 (.net core). It is a long-running process that calls some external API and stores the result in DB. The problem is that it only completes 50% of the time it runs. Other times I get an exception:

> Container is disposed and should not be used: Container is disposed.
> You may include Dispose stack-trace into the message via:
> container.With(rules => rules.WithCaptureContainerDisposeStackTrace())

**Monitor log:**

[image]

**Monitor log:**
[image]

**Failure:**
[image]

What should I be looking at? It works fine when I run it locally.
In my data miner, I have this (is the exception related to AzureFunction or my code)?

```
public DataMiner(ILogger<DataMiner> logger, IApiClientFactory apiClientFactory, IOptions<DataMinerOptions> options,
    IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _apiClientFactory = apiClientFactory;
    _options = options.Value;
    _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
}

public async Task ProcessListingServiceAsync(string listingServiceCode, CancellationToken cancel = default)
{
    using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
    var listingServiceRepository = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRepository<ListingService>>();
    var listingServices = listingServiceRepository.Get(service => service.Enabled);

    
    ...
```

**EDIT:**
could this be a reason? Says timeout after 30 min. I did set function timeout to 2 hours. Looks like it's not being considered:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "logLevel": {
            "Functions": "Information"
        },
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        }
    },

    "functionTimeout": "02:00:00"
}
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:**
For some reason host.json is not able to load, any ideas?:
I do see host.json loaded in my other functions that I have deployed

[image]

Comment: 90% chance you missed an `await` somewhere.

Comment: Is it due to while resolving the service from `ServiceProvider` in `ProcessListingServiceAsync`? Yes, it is strange that functionTimout property is not being applied even defined in host.json. Another thing, should you consider moving to Durable functions?

Comment: If you running function with Consumption plan then max allowed functionTimeout value is 10 min only.                                                          
        https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json

Comment: Please see edit 2. for some reason host.json is not loaded :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had "runOnStartup" set in my Function which is a pretty intensive process.

```
    [Singleton]
    [Timeout("02:00:00")]
    [FunctionName("Calculator")]
    public async Task Calculator([TimerTrigger("%CalculatorScheduleTriggerTime%", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo timer)
    {
          .....
```

This made my function fire off right away after deployment, causing my settings not to load/or load after few minutes:

> runOnStartup  RunOnStartup    If true, the function is invoked when the
> runtime starts. For example, the runtime starts when the function app
> wakes up after going idle due to inactivity. when the function app
> restarts due to function changes, and when the function app scales
> out. So runOnStartup should rarely if ever be set to true, especially
> in production.